# cant save data to firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I cant save any data to my firebase database.

I dont get any errors on the site, but no matter what i do, the when i look in the firebase its only null and never change.

here is my code.
**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Site</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-app.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-database.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="func2.js" type="module"></script>       <!--  your js file here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="buildingDiv">
            <h1 id="SellTitle" class="centerAlian">קבלו הצעת מחיר משוערת</h1>                                                     <!--  id for Or  הוא מציק לי -->
            מספר קומות: <input type="text" id="floorNum" name="floorNum"> </br>
            גודל קומה:  
            <select id="floorSize" name="floorSize">
                <option value="Empty"> -- בחר אופציה -- </option>
                <option value="Small">קטן</option>
                <option value="Medium">בינוני</option>
                <option value="Large">גדול</option>
            </select></br></br>  

            מספר לובים: <input type="text" id="lobbyNum" name="lobbyNum"> </br>
            גודל לובי: 
            <select id="lobbySize" name="lobbySize">
                <option value="Empty"> -- בחר אופציה -- </option>
                <option value="Small">קטן</option>
                <option value="Medium">בינוני</option>
                <option value="Large">גדול</option>
            </select></br></br>

            מספר חלונות: <input type="text" id="windowsNum" name="windowsNum"> </br></br>

            האם יש חניון?:
            <select id="parkingLot" name="parkingLot">
                <option value="No">לא</option>
                <option value="Yes">כן</option>
            </select> </br>
            גודל חניון:        <!-- Show only if the select on yes -->
            <select id="parkingSize" name="parkingSize">
                <option value="Empty"> -- בחר אופציה -- </option>
                <option value="Small">קטן</option>
                <option value="Medium">בינוני</option>
                <option value="Large">גדול</option>
            </select></br></br>


            האם יש חדר אשפה?:
            <select id="garbageRoom" name="garbageRoom">
                <option value="No">לא</option>
                <option value="Yes">כן</option>
            </select> </br>
            גודל חדר אשפה:       <!-- Show only if the select on yes -->
            <select id="garbageSize" name="garbageSize">
                <option value="Empty"> -- בחר אופציה -- </option>
                <option value="Small">קטן</option>
                <option value="Medium">בינוני</option>
                <option value="Large">גדול</option>
            </select></br></br>

            
            האם יש גינה?:
            <select id="garden" name="garden">
                <option value="No">לא</option>
                <option value="Yes">כן</option>
            </select> </br>
            גודל גינה:              <!-- Show only if the select on yes -->
            <select id="gardenSize" name="gardenSize">
                <option value="Empty"> -- בחר אופציה -- </option>
                <option value="Small">קטן</option>
                <option value="Medium">בינוני</option>
                <option value="Large">גדול</option>
            </select></br></br>

            תדירות ניקיון: </br>
            <input type="radio" id="onceAWeek" name="cleaningFrequency" value="OnceAWeek"> פעם בשבוע</br>
            <input type="radio" id="twiceAWeek" name="cleaningFrequency" value="TwiceAWeek"> פעמיים בשבוע </br>
            <input type="radio" id="ThreeAWeek" name="cleaningFrequency" value="ThreeAWeek"> שלוש פעמים בשבוע</br></br>
            <button type="button" class="centerAlian">קבל הצעת מחיר משוערת</button>              <!-- Add onclick function, the next p tag is for the results (unhide and put result)-->
            <p style="visibility: visible;" id="priceResult" class="centerAlian"></p>מחיר כלשהו</p>
            </div>


            <div id="clientDiv">
            <h1>פרטי לקוח</h1>
            עיר: 
            <select id="city" name="city">
                <option value="Akko">עכו</option>       
                <option value="Nahariya">נהריה</option>
            </select></br></br>

            רחוב: <input type="text" id="street" name="street"> </br></br>

            מספר ביניין: <input type="text" id="buildingNum" name="buildingNum"> </br></br>
            <div id="person1Div">
            <h3>איש קשר 1</h3>
            שם פרטי: <input type="text" id="fName1" name="fName1"></br></br>
            שם משפחה: <input type="text" id="lName1" name="lName1"></br></br>
            מספר טלפון: <input type="text" id="phone1" name="phone1"></br></br>
            Email: <input type="text" id="email1" name="email1"></br></br>
            </div>
            <div id="person2Div">
            <h3 id="person2Title">איש קשר 2</h3>
            שם פרטי: <input type="text" id="fName2" name="fName2"></br></br>
            שם משפחה: <input type="text" id="lName2" name="lName2"></br></br>
            מספר טלפון: <input type="text" id="phone2" name="phone2"></br></br>
            Email: <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2"></br></br>
            </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            בקשות מיוחדות:</br> <textarea name="specialRequest" rows="8" cols="50">הכנס את הבקשה שלך</textarea> </br></br>

            <button type="button" onclick="ordernow()">שליחת טופס</button>                         <!-- Add onclick function -->
            <button type="button" onclick="">ניקוי טופס</button>                         <!-- Add onclick function -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**
JS**

```
// firebase server data
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-database.js";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***************************,
  authDomain: "***************************,
  databaseURL: "***************************",
  projectId: "***************************",
  storageBucket: "***************************",
  messagingSenderId: "***************************",
  appId: "***************************"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);
// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service


function ordernow(){
  // Get all items
  var floorNum = document.getElementById('floorNum').value;
  var floorSize = document.getElementById('floorSize').value;
  var lobbyNum = document.getElementById('lobbyNum').value;
  var lobbySize = document.getElementById('lobbySize').value;
  var windowsNum = document.getElementById('windowsNum').value;
  var parkingLot = document.getElementById('parkingLot').value;
  var parkingSize = document.getElementById('parkingSize').value;
  var garbageRoom = document.getElementById('garbageRoom').value;
  var garbageSize = document.getElementById('garbageSize').value;
  var garden = document.getElementById('garden').value;
  var gardenSize = document.getElementById('gardenSize').value;
  var onceAWeek = document.getElementById('onceAWeek').checked;
  var twiceAWeek = document.getElementById('twiceAWeek').checked;
  var ThreeAWeek = document.getElementById('ThreeAWeek').checked;
  var CleaningPerWeek = onceAWeek ? "lowonceAWeek" : (twiceAWeek ? "twiceAWeek" : (ThreeAWeek ? "ThreeAWeek" : "none"));
  var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var street = document.getElementById('street').value;
  var buildingNum = document.getElementById('buildingNum').value;
  var fName1 = document.getElementById('fName1').value;
  var lName1 = document.getElementById('lName1').value;
  var phone1 = document.getElementById('phone1').value;
  var email1 = document.getElementById('email1').value;
  var fName2 = document.getElementById('fName2').value;
  var lName2 = document.getElementById('lName2').value;
  var phone2 = document.getElementById('phone2').value;
  var email2 = document.getElementById('email2').value;

  set(ref(db, 'client/' + phone1), {
  Contact1: {FirstName: fName1, LastName:lName1, PhoneNumber: phone1,email: email1},
  Contact2: {FirstName: fName2, LastName:lName2, PhoneNumber: phone2,email: email2},
  Address: {City: city, sStreet: street, BuildingNum: buildingNum},
  BuildingData: {Floors: floorNum,FloorSize: floorSize,Lobbys: lobbyNum,Lobbysize: lobbySize,
  Winows: windowsNum, ParkingLot: parkingLot, ParkingLotSize: parkingSize, GarbageRoom: garbageRoom,
  GarbageRoomSize: garbageSize,Garden: garden,GardenSize: gardenSize},
  CleaningPerWeek:CleaningPerWeek
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Data successfully written to Firebase');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error writing to Firebase: ', error);
});
}
```

Comment: At the end of your JavaScript code, there are two `console.log` statements. Does either of those show up in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: Do you successfully get authenticated? I am assuming that you can communicate with the Firebase backend and there is no authentication or connection error? Edit: You should clean up this code. If you have deduced that it is a problem which is somehow connected to firebase, we don't need to see all the `getElementById` statements or the thousand variables. Could you change your question so that all the data (firstname, lastname) is static?

Comment: Weird you have non-closed strings like `apiKey: "***************************,`

Comment: Have you set up `Firebase Rules`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: The firebasde rules set to true on wright and to read,
none problem in console.log didnt show any problem,
i removoed the api key and all of that from the code,
i tried to change it to staic and still have dont any thing

Answer (score 0):

That like of code in the head of the HTML fixed the problem:

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.14.1-0/firebase.js"></script>        <script src="func2.js"></script>       <!--  your js file here -->
    </head>
```